# Mobile dropdown menu not going into a column

Tags: html, css

When I try to make it responsive for mobile the links don't go into a flexbox column I want it to and instead stays as a row. How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like you have the flex-direction always set as `column` you'll need to set the flex-direction of your elements to `row` when you're in mobile.

Comment: flex-direction: column; is only used in the media query so I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you tried to apply flex direction and flex display on elements, but you need to specify flex direction and flex display on the container of the elements in your case the "ul"

```
ul{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

inside your media query will do

https://codepen.io/lucacel/pen/ExNNjMY

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for being clueless, this seems like it should be something obvious.

Comment: No need to sorry, more pairs of eyes are always better than one :D